# Struts2 Dojo does not display output

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2, dojo

I have a problem with struts2 dojo. In my jsp, nothing is displayed.
i'm using Struts-dojo-plugin in eclipse 
i need your helps 
This is my code:

my class action

```
public class BooksTreeAction extends ActionSupport
{
/**
 * 
 */

private static final long serialVersionUID = 8854378801207110908L;


 @Override
public String execute() throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return SUCCESS;
}
public Book getBooksTree() {

  Book bk = new Book();
  bk.setBookId("BK005");
  bk.setBookName("Java Books");
  Book bk2 = new Book();
  bk2.setBookId("BK003");
  bk2.setBookName("Java Books");
  Book bk3 = new Book();
  bk3.setBookId("BK004");
  bk3.setBookName("Java Books");
  Book bk4 = new Book();
  bk4.setBookId("BK002");
  bk4.setBookName("Java Books");

  Book bk1 = new Book();
  bk1.setBookId("C001");
  bk1.setBookName("Books");
  List list = new ArrayList();
  list.add(bk);
  list.add(bk4);
  list.add(bk3);
  list.add(bk2);
  bk1.setBooksList(list);


  return bk1;
}
```

my ex.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="/struts-dojo-tags" prefix="sx" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<sx:head/>

</head>
<body>

test tree

<sx:datetimepicker name="deliverydate" label="Delivery Date"
         displayFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" />
<div>
                <sx:tree id="treeOfBooks" rootNode="%{booksTree}" 
            nodeIdProperty="bookId" nodeTitleProperty="bookName" 
            childCollectionProperty="booksList"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the result

[image: result]

source code ex.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    // Dojo configuration
    djConfig = {
        isDebug: false,
        bindEncoding: "UTF-8"
          ,baseRelativePath: "/test0/struts/dojo/"
          ,baseScriptUri: "/test0/struts/dojo/"
         ,parseWidgets : false

    };
</script>



  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"
        src="/test0/struts/dojo/struts_dojo.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"
        src="/test0/struts/ajax/dojoRequire.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/test0/struts/xhtml/styles.css" type="text/css"/>

<script language="JavaScript" src="/test0/struts/utils.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="/test0/struts/xhtml/validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="/test0/struts/css_xhtml/validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>

test tree

<tr>
    <td class="tdLabel"><label for="widget_972324328" class="label">Delivery Date:</label></td>
    <td
><div
     dojoType="struts:StrutsDatePicker"    id="widget_972324328"    name="deliverydate"    inputName="dojo.deliverydate"    displayFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"  saveFormat="rfc"></div>
</td>
</tr>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">djConfig.searchIds.push("widget_972324328");</script>

<div>
                 <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        dojo.require("dojo.lang.*");
        dojo.require("dojo.widget.*");
        dojo.require("dojo.widget.Tree");
        // dojo.hostenv.writeIncludes();
        -->
 </script>
<div dojoType="struts:StrutsTree"   
    id="treeOfBooks"
    toggle="fade"
    >

<div dojoType="struts:StrutsTreeNode" title="Books" id="C001">

<div dojoType="struts:StrutsTreeNode" title="Java Books" id="BK005">
</div>

<div dojoType="struts:StrutsTreeNode" title="Java Books" id="BK002">
</div>

<div dojoType="struts:StrutsTreeNode" title="Java Books" id="BK004">
</div>

<div dojoType="struts:StrutsTreeNode" title="Java Books" id="BK003">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    djConfig.searchIds.push("treeSelector_treeOfBooks");
    djConfig.searchIds.push("treeOfBooks");
</script>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: S2 dojo plugin is deprecated.

Comment: I've hit this on dojo datetimepicker 4 years ago. Lost two days comparing the code and libraries with another project (made by me) where it worked, and they were absolutely identical... but one wasn't working. Then I switched to jQuery datepicker, and lived peacefully. Never known which the problem was, though.